# Get Java Class name from generic List type

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

I have a method with 1 List, generic class inside:

```
public static String classTypeOfList(List<T> list) {
    return T.getName(); //in my mind...
}
```

The code is wrong, but you can see, what I want. If i call this method like this:

```
List<MyObject> list;
System.out.println("the type of the list is: "+classTypeOfList(list));
```

I would like to get this result:

```
the type of the list is: MyObject
```

How could I get the name of a generic type class? Or if I can't get it this way, than could you show me an another option?
Thank you!

Comment: You can't they get erased on compilation.

Comment: use getClass() method that gives you class name at runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of `Type Erasure`, you will not be able to get the type(in case of Empty List).As JLS says on Type Erasure :

**4.6. Type Erasure**

> Type erasure is a mapping from types (possibly including parameterized
>   types and type variables) to types (that are never parameterized types
>   or type variables). We write |T| for the erasure of type T. The
>   erasure mapping is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> The erasure of a parameterized type (§4.5) G<T1,...,Tn> is |G|.
>
> The erasure of a nested type T.C is |T|.C.
>
> The erasure of an array type T[] is |T|[].
>
> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.
>
> The erasure of every other type is the type itself.
> ```
>
> Type erasure also maps the signature (§8.4.2) of a constructor or
>   method to a signature that has no parameterized types or type
>   variables. The erasure of a constructor or method signature s is a
>   signature consisting of the same name as s and the erasures of all the
>   formal parameter types given in s.
>
> The type parameters of a constructor or method (§8.4.4), and the
>   return type (§8.4.5) of a method, also undergo erasure if the
>   constructor or method's signature is erased.
>
> The erasure of the signature of a generic method has no type
>   parameters.

## In case of Non Empty List:

```
......
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

List<MyObject> list= new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        list.add(new MyObject());
        System.out.println("the type of the list is: "+classTypeOfList(list));
}

public static <T> String classTypeOfList(List<T> list) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return list.get(0).getClass().getCanonicalName(); 
}
```

### OUTPUT

```
the type of the list is: MyObject
```

Comment: "In case of Non Empty List:" does not work in general because 1) `list.get(0)` might be `null`, and 2) `list.get(0).getClass()` may be a subclass of `T`

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, this cannot be done. Generics only exist at compile time. At runtime this information is erased and at runtime your `List<MyObject>` will simply turn into `List`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be little ( or very ) different from question, since it is long enough for the comment, so i am posting it as answer.

I found this question interesting and hence gave it a try. My attempt is following, i got the `Type` of the class, so i thought it is worth sharing and getting experts opinion back on my approach

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
    B b1 = new B();
    listB.add(b1);

    List<C> listC = new ArrayList<>();
    C c1 = new C();
    listC.add(c1);

    A a = new A();
    a.method(listB);
    a.method(listC);

}

public <T> void method(List<T> list) {

    System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass().getName());
}
}

class B {

}

class C {

}
```

Output i got was `B` and `C`

Comment: This does not work in general because 1) `list` may not have an element at index 0, 2) `list.get(0)` might be `null`, and 3) `list.get(0).getClass()` may be a subclass of `T`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getClass()` on the object. After you get the class object you can use `getName()` to retrieve the class name.

Comment: "on the object" what object?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get class:

```
Class<T> clazz = ((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
```

You can read more about it on this [link](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/02/07/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/).

Comment: This is not relevant to this question. This is only for cases where the object is a subclass that implements the interface with a specific type argument.